# Convert C Cast Macro To C++ Function

Tags: c++

I am working with a C library that uses the usual C "inheritance" trick

```cpp
typedef struct Base_ *BasePointer;
struct Base_ {
};

typedef struct Derived_ *DerivedPointer;
struct Derived_ {
  Base_ header;
};

#define BaseCast(obj) ((BasePointer)(obj))

void bar(BasePointer);

void foo(DerivedPointer derived)
{
  bar(BaseCast(derived));
}
```

I am writing some C++ utilities and one such utility is a safer `BaseCast()` using type traits to check that the object is indeed derived. This `BaseCast()` must be completely interchangeable with the macro. I have the following but *can this be done better?*

```cpp
// convertible_to_base checks for existence of object->header
// and that object->header is of type Base_

template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] static inline constexpr BasePointer& BaseCast(T& object) noexcept
{
  static_assert(util::convertible_to_base<T>::value, "");
  return reinterpret_cast<BasePointer&>(object);
}

template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] static inline constexpr const BasePointer& BaseCast(const T& object) noexcept
{
  static_assert(util::convertible_to_base<T>::value, "");
  return reinterpret_cast<const BasePointer&>(object);
}
```

I don't like the `reinterpret_cast()`, but I could not get this to work any other way.

Comment: why do you need the cast? If you already checked that `object` has a `header` , why dont you simply return `object.header` ?

Comment: `object.header` is of type `Base_` not `Base`. I see the typenames are a bit too similar, I will amend them to make this more clear :)

Comment: well then return `*(object.header)` ?

Comment: i am still confused by the alias ;), though one is `T` the other is `T*`, isnt it just a matter of dereferencing/taking the address?

Comment: I need to return the pointer, not the value

Comment: I agree with @463035818_is_not_a_number, just return a reference to the member `header` variable. The `reinterpret_cast` here will only ever be valid if the type of `T` is always a standard layout type and is the first member of the class.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, `T` hides the pointer in this case i.e. it is `DerivedPointer` (a.k.a. `struct Derived_ *`). I leave it generic (i.e. not `T*`) because the `static_assert()` provides a more precise error diagnostic than "no available overload for `BaseCast()`" in case the user does not pass in a pointer.

Comment: @DXPower `convertible_to_base` checks that `T` is standard layout, as any arguments will always be a (pointer to) C struct.

Comment: Now your example is even more confusing. You're now returning a constant reference to a base pointer... why not just return `BasePointer` itself? In fact, it may even be misleading because the `const` here applies to the stored pointer variable, not the `Base` type (which I can't tell which your want). Your type aliases are serving you absolutely 0 assistance here.

Comment: You know that `object` has a member `header`. And you want to return either that member or its address or the reference after dereferencing, thats the confusing part, but that confusion is actually not that relevant, because what you want to return is one of those three: `object.header` / `*object.header` / `&object.header`. No?

Comment: @DXPower look closely. `Derived_`s first member is `Base_` i.e. the value *not* a pointer. I am in effect returning a reference to the result of `return &object->header;` but cannot do that since that returns a reference to temporary.

Comment: "but cannot do that since that returns a reference to temporary. " would be good if you'd write taht in the quesiton, would make things a lot clearer

Comment: ...and why do you want to return a const ref rather than just the pointer?

Comment: > would be good if you'd write taht in the quesiton, would make things a lot clearer. Not sure I follow. returning a reference to result of `&` operator is *always* A Bad Thing.

Comment: Good point, I suppose I could simply return the pointer value in the `const` case yes.

Comment: Totally agreed with @463035818_is_not_a_number. It is a lot better to not rely on additional properties of the types such as standard layout and the relative position of the member variable compared to the others. The single property of "check if T has member header" is enough to retrieve it. No reinterpret_cast required.

In C++20, `std::is_pointer_interconvertible_with_class` was added to check if a class can be pointer interconverted (aka reinterpret_cast) with one of its members. Consider adding this to your trait. I made a godbolt demonstrating this: https://godbolt.org/z/6EEqe6dWE

Comment: What is definition of convertible_to_base

Comment: Never use `reinterpret_cast` to cast between classes in an inheritance hierarchy. It is completely illegal, even though it sometimes works in some implementations.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. `reinterpret_cast()` is perfectly legal and well defined here  so long as `T` has `Base_` as the first member and is `standard_layout`.

Comment: Hm I see you don't actually have a class hierarchy, "base" it's just an unfortunate name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post this as answer because discussion in comments got stuck somehow and I don't see why it is not an alternative. Return the pointer by value:

```
template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] static inline constexpr BasePointer BaseCast(const T& object) noexcept
{
  static_assert(util::convertible_to_base<T>::value, "");
  return &object.header;
}
```

As you mentioned, the reference would be a reference to a temporary, hence the non-const ref would be of little use anyhow.